# Development environment for Sharepoint Apps in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

Can anybody tell me the reasons of having a public IP in the Virtual Machine that will host all the Apps that will developed and integrated in Sharepoint Online.

If also there is some official links that talks about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing from where you read about this "having a public IP in the Virtual Machine that will host all the Apps that will developped and integrated in Sharepoint Online." (it seem someone one made this as demo or how to do)

about SharePoint apps, there is two type,

- SharePoint hosted apps: do need to code behind and you can deploy to any SharePoint site.
- Provider-hosted apps: need code behind and you need to host out side SharePoint on cloud to allow SharePoint access this app. and this will help you to extend SharePoint sites without effect there servers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your responce.
I got this from a formation that i had about developpement in SP Online.
If i have to developp an eventReceiver. my VM that host the provider app should be public.

Is this true :)

Comment: yes, SharePoint online need to call you event receiver, how SharePoint online can access if it is a private IP? then it should be public. after complete your development and test it, you will deploy these services on cloud and also they will have an Public IP